# Debug a .net Class Library with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, class-library, build-events

### The Situation

I've been hit with a situation that I've never encountered before.  I have an application that uses a `dll` called `client.dll`.  The Application stays in the `bin\debug\` folder and is run using *Build Events...* every time the application builds.  This works great, the program starts after the program is built and everything goes smoothly... *until...*

*AN EXCEPTION/ERROR IS THROWN!*  The application is no longer being debugged because VS2010 isn't actually connected to the DLL any more.

---

### My Question

Do any of you know a better way for me to handle this?  Is there anyway for me to line-by-line debug like I would a normal WinForms application with this Class Library project?

---

### Information

**Build Events:** *CALL "$(SolutionDir)Client\bin\Debug\ClientRunner.exe"*

Comment: Can you attach to the running process? (in a separate visual studio, debug->attach to process and select the clientrunner process)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The debugger was never attached in the first place.  Don't do this with a build event.  Instead, configure the debugger to run your ClientRunner.exe process whenever you start debugging with F5.  Project + Properties, Debug tab.  Tick the "Start external program" option and select your .exe.

You'll want to set a debug break in your class library source code, wherever you want to start debugging.  And press F5.

Adding the project that created ClientRunner.exe to your solution and making it the Startup project could of course work too.